# I need an object to follow a line

Tags: python, python-3.x

As I said I have to do an animation and the one I chose to do is for object, in this case snow, to follow a line which would go zig-zag from left to right. I am trying to crate an animation of a snow falling on small house. I also have a problem with generating more * with one command. I want them to be apart from each other. If you have any improvements you can also share them if you want. I just need it in less than a week.

So I started by importing tkinter and random, as I know i will use them. I then defined a house and snow as two things or objects. I know will have to make an line which will be later turned white or blue to make it invisible. I need help to do the thing with generating * every 20 pixels. Here is the code:

```
import tkinter
import random
Canvas=tkinter.Canvas(width=1000, height=1000)
Canvas.pack()

sx=10
sy=10
x=200
y=300

def barak(x,y):
    Canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+300, y+150, fill="brown", outline="red")
    Canvas.create_rectangle(x+80, y+80, x+120, y+120, fill="yellow", outline="red")
    Canvas.create_rectangle(x+200, y+80, x+240, y+150, fill="black", outline="red")
    Canvas.create_polygon(x, y, x+150, y-100, x+300, y, fill="dark red", outline="red")


Canvas.create_line(x+400,y-300, x+450,y-250, x+400,y-200, x+450,y-150, x+400,y-100, x+450,y-50, x+400,y, x+450,y+50, x+400,y+100, x+450,y+150, x+400,y+200, x+450,y+250)

barak(x,y)

def sneh(x,y):
    Canvas.create_text(sx, sy, font="arial 15 ", text="*", fill="green")

sneh(x,y)
    
for i in range(1, 500, 20):
    sneh(x+i,y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Snow Animation")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=800, height=600, bg="light blue")
canvas.pack()

house_x, house_y = 200, 300

def draw_house(x, y):
    canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + 300, y + 150, fill="brown", outline="red")
    canvas.create_rectangle(x + 80, y + 80, x + 120, y + 120, fill="yellow", outline="red")
    canvas.create_rectangle(x + 200, y + 80, x + 240, y + 150, fill="black", outline="red")
    canvas.create_polygon(x, y, x + 150, y - 100, x + 300, y, fill="dark red", outline="red")

def draw_snowflake(x, y):
    canvas.create_text(x, y, font="arial 15 ", text="❄", fill="white")

def animate_snow():
    # Clear previous snowflakes
    canvas.delete("snowflake")

    # Draw snowflakes at random positions above the house
    for _ in range(10):
        x = random.randint(house_x, house_x + 300)
        y = random.randint(house_y - 100, house_y)
        draw_snowflake(x, y)
    
    # Move the snowflakes downwards
    canvas.move("snowflake", 0, 5)

    # Schedule the next animation frame
    root.after(100, animate_snow)

# Draw the house
draw_house(house_x, house_y)

# Start the snow animation
animate_snow()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried it and it is very nice but not exactly what I wanted. It does help me with snowflake generating problem, but I wanted them to fall down ad follow zig zag pattern. I know how to make them fall i just need them to follow the pattern. I will try to combine it with my code and maybe I will figure it out later or ask my father when he has some time. 
Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok so I used your code and fixed it to work as expected.